# Simular hover de css con código

Tags: javafx

Quiero detectar cuándo el puntero del ratón pasa por encima de un control. En `CSS` lo haría con `.miControl:hover{...}`, pero ¿Cómo se hace en código JavaFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear un listener a la propiedad `hoverProperty` del control:

```
miControl.hoverProperty().addListener((ov, valorAntiguo, valorNuevo) -> {
    if (valorNuevo == true) {
        // estamos encima del control
    } else {
        // estamos fuera del control
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar is() de jQuery:

```
$('#elem').is(":hover"); // Retornaría true o false
```

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Bindings. Aquí tienes un ejemplo válido para botones y campos de texto:

```
miControl.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(miControl.hoverProperty())
        .then("Estamos encima")
        .otherwise("Estamos fuera"));
```